# How to solve Codeigniter .htaccess error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've the following rules on .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I'm getting this error
[image]

What to do?

Comment: Provide the class definition of Default model. Also provide next line of exception message. Have you added model name to autoload array? Ex: ```$autoload['model'] = array('default_model');```

Comment: But i've loaded the model on that page.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Finding the model has nothing to do with `.htaccess'. Show where you try to load the model.

Comment: This is not an htaccess problem. Put the model in the autoload and see if that helps. Check all your spelling

Comment: Put the code where you are loading model in ```School.php```.

Comment: I've developed it locally without any problem.

Comment: I've solved it. My model name was in lower case I've made it UC first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. My model name was in lower case I've made it UC first. Thanks.
    ***default_model.php*** to ***Default_model.php***

Answer (score 1):

When creating models, you need to place the file in application/models/ and name the file in all lowercase - like default_model.php

Also one thing is important :

Your model file name must be **ucfirst**.

The default_model.php should contain the following:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Default_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: yes show i also told you that you have to use ucfirst not lower case.

Comment: i just bold it see my answer.

Comment: and if it is right answer as you mentioned please give upvote.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this one hope so it will helpful for you.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer? Why exactly is the file given by the OP wrong, what have you changed to make it work?

Comment: in my .htaccess file the index.php file is run directly run, and all the other files like index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico run directly so there no chance to make a mistake. it works like this.

Comment: not worked. but I've solved it. My model name was in lower case I've made it UC first. Thanks.

Comment: Please add all explanation to the answer, not to the comment section. Additionally, explain how such a change that works for you affects the OPs problem. As I would assume by the error message given in the screenshot, there is no connection to other request URIs

Answer (score 0):

try to use this htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer? Why exactly is the file given by the OP wrong, what have you changed to make it work?

Comment: not worked. but I've solved it. My model name was in lower case I've made it UC first. Thanks.